# linked JS not running on slow webserver

Tags: javascript, html, xampp

I have a probably very simple problem that is completely spoofing me.

I have got a web server (XAMPP) running off a reasonably slow usb stick.
I've got a very simple file structure:

```
--htdocs  
  --projects
    --callback  
      index.html  
        --js
          jquery-1.9.1.min.js
          callbackclient.js  
        --css
          main.css
```

For some reason, I can't get a simple linked script working:
Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/callbackclient.js' type='text/javacsript'></script>
    <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      tester();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

And here's my callbackclient.js:
`function tester(){ console.log("test");
}`

When I hit `localhost/projects/callback` the browser displays "This is a test" as expected, but I get an error in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: tester is not defined`

I get the same if I try to run tester(); from console directly, yet `$("head")` correctly selects the head element which I guess means jQuery is being loaded fine.

I must have missed something fundamental - someone please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you misspelled the type on the script tag. `text/javacsript` instead of `text/javascript`

Comment: This is very likely it. I will check tomorrow when I'm back on my development PC & accept the answer! I knew it would be something silly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your callbackClient.js:

```
var tester = function (){ console.log("test"); }
```

If that works, you just need to have the function be set to a variable, and then call it.  If that doesn't work, then I would just remove the JS code on your HTML page and do this inside your callbackClient.js:

```
jQuery(function () {
    // Logic here
    console.log('this is working, right?');

    var functionName = function () {
        console.log('blah blah blah')
    }

    functionName();
})
```

Hope that helps!